# Pinterest board widget CSS styling

Tags: javascript, css, web, widget, pinterest

I've been stuck on this for the last hour and a half and can't solve it. 
So, I know pinterest widgets reset their class on page load, I have managed to get the widget looking as good as I can be bothered with, now just one element needs to go.

In the following link, at the bottom, you can see the widget - and the 'see on' box thing. This is what needs to go.

http://innov8web.co.uk/new3/

I have tried everything I can think of. Code snippets attached. Any help will be appreciated.

```
a.PIN_1394396792408_embed_grid_ft{display:none!important;}
#pinterest-widget a.PIN_1394396792408_embed_grid_ft{display:none!important;}
#pinterest-widget span a.PIN_1394396792408_embed_grid_ft{display:none!important;}
#pinterest-widget span span a.PIN_1394396792408_embed_grid_ft{display:none!important;}


a.PIN_1394395968955_embed_grid.PIN_1394395968955_fancy{display:none!important;}
.PIN_1394395968955_embed_grid.PIN_1394395968955_fancy{display:none!important;}
```

And the javascript I have tried

```
<script>
function addNewStyle(newStyle) {
    var styleElement = document.getElementById('styles_js');
    if (!styleElement) {
        styleElement = document.createElement('style');
        styleElement.type = 'text/css';
        styleElement.id = 'styles_js';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(styleElement);
    }
    styleElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(newStyle));
}

addNewStyle('span a.PIN_1394396792408_embed_grid_ft{display:none !important;}')
</script>
```

So, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
function removeSeeOn(){
     var el = document.getElementById("pinterest-widget").getElementsByTagName("a");
     el[el.length-1].style.display = "none !important";
}
```

This is assuming there is only one element with that class name (which it seems like there is). Add this function to your script then add `removeSeeOn();` to your `body`'s `onload` attribute.

If that doesn't work you could try adding this to your css:

```
#pinterest-widget>span>a {
     display:none !important;
}
```

This is another way to do the same thing:

```
#pinterest-widget span a:only-of-type {
     display:none !important;
}
```

Comment: I made some edits. try it now. I didn't notice you already had an onload in the body tag.

Comment: Yes, but I did have a breakthrough. The class name changes everytime the widget is called. So it needs to be found a different way. There is a way, I know it.

Comment: I just want my widget to work haha! Also, I have 0 knowledge of java coding - but cant you do like #widget-box > span > a in the classes?

Comment: Yes, that's is basically the change I just made. Impressive suggestion for someone with no javascript experience. I suggest you start learning. You seem like a natural.

Comment: Thanks - I've been coding for years, just always been scared off by the messyness of javascript..

Anyway, my body tag now looks like this: 


<body onload="MM_preloadImages('img/carousel/sov-h.png','img/carousel/elite-h.png','img/carousel/bcc-h.png','img/work/signs-h.png','img/work/sov-h.png','img/work/bcc-h.png'); removeSeeOn();">


But it still doesnt seem to work?? @peter

Comment: It's a beautiful mess. Once you get into it you'll understand. Try the second part of my answer instead. I think it doesn't like adding the "!important" part.

Answer (score 3):

I have successfully styled Pinterest embedded widgets using pure CSS.

The following code removes the title, border, background, and link, leaving you with nothing but the images. It assumes you have your widget contained in a div with the class "pinterest". Tweak to get the result you want:

```
div.pinterest > span > a {
  display: none !important;
}
div.pinterest > span span:first-child {
  display: none !important;
}
div.pinterest > span {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent !important;
  background: transparent none !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```